# GWT Custom Library Dependency issues

Tags: gwt, gwt-maven-plugin

I have created a library of widgets that export to a jar and reuse in several other projects. In my library, I depend on a few other jars in my war/WEB-INF/lib. The problem is that when I use my library in another project the dependencies of the library do not get carried over so I have to add those jars to the classpath and inherit them in the project as well. There has got to be a better way to handle the dependencies, do I need to use maven or is there another practice that works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, if you don't want to manually manage your dependencies you will have to use a dependency management system. The 3 big ones are Maven, Ivy, and Gradle. I have included links below so you can read about them. A quick search will reveal the pros/cons of each from the community and also information about alternative dependency management systems. There are quite a few out there.

[Apache Maven](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html)

[Apache Ivy](http://ant.apache.org/ivy/history/latest-milestone/tutorial/start.html)

[Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/)